# iterate through hashmap in freemarker

Tags: java, freemarker

I have a hashmap like below

```
HashMap<String, String> testStatus = new HashMap<String, String>();
Map root = new HashMap();

public void fmTest() {

testStatus.put("one","1");
testStatus.put("two","2");
testStatus.put("three","3");
root.put("status", testStatus);
testStatus.clear();
}
```

**My FTL:**

```
<#list status?keys as key> 
${key} = ${status[key]}
</#list>
```

Above code is just an example. My question is if I loop the testStatus hashmap to have different values in each loop and clear at the end of loop... how can I have the freemarker to display the key-value pair of testStatus hashmap from each loop.

If I don't clear the testStatus hashmap I get accumulated result. But if I clear the testStatus hashmap the freemarker displays nothing..

Comment: When you do `root.put("status","testStatus")` it is maintaining the reference to same `HashMap`. It is not creating a copy of the `testStatus` HashMap. Hence, when you `clear()` it, all its contents are cleared. I think to achieve what you want do,  create and assign a `new testStatus HashMap` inside your loop at the beginning.

Comment: I tried that. It didn't work. Free marker still displays the result of the hashmap from last loop.

Comment: I think your problem is not with freemarker, It's obvious that clearing the testStatus would result in freemarker display nothing but what is interesting is that if you don't the testStatus show accumumalted results I think that your example is insufficent I would ask you to show us the whole method, loops etc... to detect the problem

Comment: @user1629109: your code sample is not enough for us to guess what happened. Please post the real code for: "Above code is just an example. My question is if I loop the testStatus hashmap to have different values in each loop and clear at the end of loop... how can I have the freemarker to display the key-value pair of testStatus hashmap from each loop."

Answer (score 0):

```
HashMap<String, String> testStatus = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

put this declaration into the fmTest method, then when every time you invoke the method,a new Map will be put into the root, so they won't be accumulated...